# How can I listen to video metadata in videojs?

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I'd like to be able to capture events that are being fired from my `rtmp` live video using videojs.

When I listen to `loadedmetadata` event there is nothing useful coming back from player. can I use this event to accomplish what I want.

PS:
I know there is a open PR for that #2928 but it seems like it's not going to be merged any soon.